# Select different fields from more than one table in SQL Server using Inner Join

Tags: sql-server, join, inner-join

This won't display results

```
SELECT IMSLogin.AccountType, IMSLogin.Status, Registration.UsrFLname, Registration.UsrEmail, Employee.EMPID, Students.STUID, Employee.EMPDEPT, Franchise.FrArea, Franchise.FrName 
FROM Registration 
INNER JOIN IMSLogin ON Registration.RegId = IMSLogin.RegId 
INNER JOIN Employee ON Registration.RegId = Employee.RegId 
INNER JOIN Students ON Registration.RegId = Students.RegId 
INNER JOIN Franchise ON Registration.RegId = Franchise.RegId
```

But if i give below, will give the right results

```
SELECT Registration.UsrFLname, Registration.UsrEmail, Students.STUID, Students.Pay_type, IMSLogin.AccountType, IMSLogin.Status 
FROM IMSLogin 
INNER JOIN Registration ON IMSLogin.RegId = Registration.RegId 
INNER JOIN Students ON Registration.RegId = Students.RegId
```

My tables:

```
Registration(RegId,PK) 
IMSLogin(RegId, FK) 
Students(RegId,FK) 
Franchise(RegId,FK) 
Employee(RegID,FK)
```

I am trying to display it in a gridview, but i need the right the query, i don't know how to use that inner join?

Plz help....

Thanks...

Comment: Check you joins on Employees and Franchise. You might need some left join.

Comment: @kostasch. yes, it was the problem....I gave all as left join instead of INNER.......Thank You.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
       l.AccountType
     , l.[Status]
     , r.UsrFLname
     , r.UsrEmail
     , e.EMPID
     , s.STUID
     , e.EMPDEPT
     , f.FrArea
     , f.FrName 
FROM dbo.Registration r
JOIN dbo.IMSLogin l ON r.RegId = l.RegId 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Students s ON r.RegId = s.RegId 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Employee e ON r.RegId = e.RegId 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Franchise f ON r.RegId = f.RegId
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your database design is poor. You should have a users table and then related tables for any specifics about students, employees or Franchises that. Your problem is that no one is probably simultaneously in Employees, Students and Franchise. You will need left joins to all three of these tables in all likelihood.

Comment: I have the same....My problem was with the Left, but i used only INNER....I gat the answer...